# how to make custom select with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some options and I want them to be selectable.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.new__order__choice .juice__box {
  border: 2px solid var(--second-sub-color);
  color: var(--second-sub-color);
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

As you see I have 7 items and I want them to be selectable. I can add CSS for this but the thing that makes me confused is when I select the other ones, I want to deselect the selected one.

It should be like this:

[image]

If you could help me with it, I would be really glad. Thanks.

Comment: When you say selectable do you want to capture some value or just let it be different visually? Because if you want to capture values you will need to use some javaScript and you have not added that code.

Comment: You just need a onclick function which first removes all the `.new__order__choice` classes from every item and the adds it back to the selected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you want is that the background color only apply to the last selected, if so you can do this in css:

```
.juice__box.selected{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

and this in jquery

```
$('.juice__box').click(function(){
    $('.juice__box').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
  
});
```

see it live in the snippet

```js
$('.juice__box').click(function(){
    $('.juice__box').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
  
});
```

```css
.juice__box {
  border: 2px solid var(--second-sub-color);
  color: var(--second-sub-color);
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.juice__box.selected{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="juice__box">Juice 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use JS for this task, you may use instead a group of radiobox and labels instead of divs.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 12px;
}

.row > div {
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 9px);
}

.juice__box {
  padding: .25rem;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px currentColor solid;
  color: #335;
  background: #ccc;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
}

:checked + .juice__box {
  color: #ccc;
  background: #335;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="radio" name="juice" value="1" id="j1" />
    <label for="j1" class="juice__box">Juice 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="radio" name="juice" value="2" id="j2" />
    <label for="j2" class="juice__box">Juice 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="radio" name="juice" value="3" id="j3" />
    <label for="j3" class="juice__box">Juice 3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="radio" name="juice" value="4" id="j4" />
    <label for="j4" class="juice__box">Juice 4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="radio" name="juice" value="5" id="j5" />
    <label for="j5" class="juice__box">Juice 5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="radio" name="juice" value="6" id="j6" />
    <label for="j6" class="juice__box">Juice 6</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   <input type="radio" name="juice" value="7" id="j7" />
    <label for="j7" class="juice__box">Juice 7</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this using HTML and CSS alone you can convert the `.juice-box` elements to `labels` and add a hidden radio `input`. Then you can listen for the `:checked` state of the input and apply the CSS styling to highlight the selected item.

As only one radio can be selected from a group you get the deselect behaviour by default, without the need for any JS code.

```css
:root {
  --second-sub-color: #00C;
}

.new__order__choice .juice__box {
  border: 2px solid var(--second-sub-color);
  color: var(--second-sub-color);
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.new__order__choice input {
  display: none;
} 
.new__order__choice input:checked + .juice__box  {
  background-color: var(--second-sub-color);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="new__order__choice">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="juice" id="juice1" value="1" />
      <label class="juice__box" for="juice1">Juice 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="juice" id="juice2" value="2" />
      <label class="juice__box" for="juice2">Juice 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="juice" id="juice3" value="3" />
      <label class="juice__box" for="juice3">Juice 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="juice" id="juice4" value="4" />
      <label class="juice__box" for="juice4">Juice 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="juice" id="juice5" value="5" />
      <label class="juice__box" for="juice5">Juice 5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="juice" id="juice6" value="6" />
      <label class="juice__box" for="juice6">Juice 6</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="juice" id="juice7" value="7" />
      <label class="juice__box" for="juice7">Juice 7</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The added benefit of this is that you don't need any further JS to retrieve the value of the selected items from the `div` elements you originally had when sending the selections in a request to the server, as they are already contained in a form control.